# Is there a way to pull a variable value into a select-object expression?

Tags: powershell, select-object

The purpose of this script is to find the Name, directory and last write time of files and output it to a csv file.

```
get-childitem D:\testing -recurse -filter *.txt | select-object Name,DirectoryName,LastWriteTime, @{Name="New_colimn";Expression={"copy-item \`"DirectoryName\`" To_Compile_directory"}} | where { $_.DirectoryName -ne $NULL } | Export-CSV D:\testing\rdf.csv
```

My problem is that there is 1 cell I want to fill with another script that takes values from the generated csv file. Is there a way to pull the value of each DirectoryName and paste it into the Expression of the same row? I only get an error that says DirectoryName is an invalid key.

when I try to pull using $*.DirectoryName the script only reads the $* and the value it has is the Name.

Thank for helping.

Comment: `Copy-Item` doesn't output anything, why would you place it in a `Select-Object` property expression?

Comment: i want to copy files after I run this script.. but I cannot pull the directory which I will use as the source..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to collect the data from the files like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\testing' -Filter '*.txt' -File -Recurse | 
Select-Object Name,DirectoryName,LastWriteTime | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\testing\rdf.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

and then have your other script read the **DirectoryName**'s from it like this?

```
$directories = (Import-Csv -Path 'D:\testing\rdf.csv').DirectoryName | Select-Object -Unique
# maybe do something with these directories here?
foreach ($folderPath in $directories) {
    # copy the directories including the files to an existing root destination folder
    Copy-Item -Path $folderPath -Destination 'D:\SomeExistingDestinationPath' -Recurse -Force
}
```

Comment: yep that is correct, first collect the data from the files like that... and then I would need my other script to read the data from prior script to execute a copy..

Comment: `$directories = (Import-Csv -Path 'D:\testing\rdf.csv').DirectoryName | Select-Object -Unique Name,DirectoryName,LastWriteTime, @{Name="New_colimn";Expression={"copy-item \`"$directories\`" To_Compile_directory"}} | where { $_.DirectoryName -ne $NULL } | Export-CSV D:\testing\rdf1.csv`

I assume my next script would look like this? I'm exporting another csv file for the second script.. apologies, I am very new to powershell.

Comment: @JohnPaulRanoa Nope, by `
$directories = (Import-Csv -Path 'D:\testing\rdf.csv').DirectoryName | Select-Object -Unique` you get an array of DirectoryNames (all strings). If you want to getg those directories in the second script and then copy them to somewhere else, please see my edit